# Where do you pass the handler info in aiohttp test case client.request

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.6, testcase, aiohttp

I was trying AioHttp TestCase library and just using the sample code given in the docs but it says `404` when I run `pytest filename.py`.

I see some examples above too, first of all I don't understand the difference between test_client and self.client. Are they both doing the same thing but just different methods?

Also, in the below implementation, where do you pass the handler info? `self.client` does not accept handler param `hello`.

```
from aiohttp.test_utils import AioHTTPTestCase, unittest_run_loop
from aiohttp import web

from aiohttp.test_utils import AioHTTPTestCase, unittest_run_loop
from aiohttp import web


async def hello(request):
   return web.Response(text='Hello')

class MyAppTestCase(AioHTTPTestCase):

   async def get_application(self):
        return web.Application()

   @unittest_run_loop
   async def test_example(self):
        request = await self.client.request("GET", "/")
        assert request.status == 200
        text = await request.text()
        assert "Hello, world" in text
```

Comment: Hey, how I can run `AioHTTPTestCase` tests? I have written some tests but I don't know how to run them? which command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

`test_client` fixture from pytest should be just factory that make is the same as `AioHTTPTestCase.client`

When I look to code in TestClient it all got down to cal `_request` that looks like this:

```
async def _request(
        self,
        method: str,
        str_or_url: StrOrURL, *,
        params: Optional[Mapping[str, str]]=None,
        data: Any=None,
        json: Any=None,
        cookies: Optional[LooseCookies]=None,
        headers: LooseHeaders=None,
        skip_auto_headers: Optional[Iterable[str]]=None,
        auth: Optional[BasicAuth]=None,
        allow_redirects: bool=True,
        max_redirects: int=10,
        compress: Optional[str]=None,
        chunked: Optional[bool]=None,
        expect100: bool=False,
        raise_for_status: Optional[bool]=None,
        read_until_eof: bool=True,
        proxy: Optional[StrOrURL]=None,
        proxy_auth: Optional[BasicAuth]=None,
        timeout: Union[ClientTimeout, object]=sentinel,
        verify_ssl: Optional[bool]=None,
        fingerprint: Optional[bytes]=None,
        ssl_context: Optional[SSLContext]=None,
        ssl: Optional[Union[SSLContext, bool, Fingerprint]]=None,
        proxy_headers: Optional[LooseHeaders]=None,
        trace_request_ctx: Optional[SimpleNamespace]=None
) -> ClientResponse:
```

So you can pass these to client and it will make the call. `data` and `json` should be the same (expecting as in `requests` it is like so), `json` just dumps it.

So something like this should work. At least for me:

```
class BookingTest(AioHTTPTestCase):

    async def get_application(self):
        return await create_test_app()

    @unittest_run_loop
    async def test_create_booking(self):
        data = {
            "my_id": "1234"
        }
        # the post data should be in request.body 
        # (we use connexion and we have it parsed as an argument to handler named body)
        resp = await self.client.request("POST", "/api/bookings", json=data)
        assert resp.status == 201

    @unittest_run_loop
    async def test_get_booking(self):
        booking_id = "1234"
        url = f"/be/api/bookings/{booking_id}"
        resp = await self.client.request("GET", url)
        assert resp.status == 200
```